# Can a Windows 11 Product Key be Used for Windows 10 Activation?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-11, active-window

Windows 11 key activate Windows 10

Can I use a Windows 11 product key to activate Windows 10?

Windows 11 cannot be run on my system for various reasons, and I have to install windows 10. I can activate my Windows 10 with a Windows 11 license

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this post it seems that you can do it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/590807/activating-windows-10-os-with-windows-11-key
Hope this can help you